# Change Tmux default shortcut to switch between sessions

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

The current shortcut is `Prefix )` and `Prefix (` to switch between sessions.

I want to change it to `Ctrl PageUp/PageDown`, but I don't know what command should be executed when I pressed these keys.

I didn't find any command to override these default prefixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is `switch-client` with `-n` (next) and `-p` (previous) options.

```
bind -n C-PageUp switch-client -p
bind -n C-PageDown switch-client -n
```

Comment: Glad you found it.  Don't forget to self-accept your answer - That will keep this from popping up again in the future. Thanks!